# How do you sort a $text search on $meta: "textScore" with Loopback?

Tags: mongodb, loopback

When interacting directly with MongoDB's api, you can do a full text search and sort on the result's score like this:

```
 db.someCollection
     .find({ $text: { $search: "some search phrase" } }, 
           {score: { "$meta":"textScore" })
     .sort({ score: { $meta:"textScore"} })
```

How do you translate this to a Loopback filter?

I have tried this, which failed:

```
 {
      "where":{ 
           "$text" : { "search":"some search phrase" } 
      },
      "fields": {
           "score":{
                "$meta":"textScore"
           }
      },
      "orderby":"score ASC"
 }
```

Unfortunately, that results in:

```
 [
   {},
   {},
   {}
 ]
```

When I look at the MongoDB profile output, I find that Loopback has generated this query:

```
   "filter" : {
        "$text" : {
            "$search" : "some search phrase"
        }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "score" : 1
    },
    "projection" : {
        "score" : 1
    }
```

So it's project the "score" as if it were a normal field rather than a $meta field... and it's as a result excluding all other fields.

How do I get loopback to generate the correct query that should look like this when executed:

```
    "filter" : {
        "$text" : {
            "$search" : "some search phrase"
        }
    },
    "sort" : {
        "score" : {
            "$meta" : "textScore"
        }
    },
    "projection" : {
        "score" : {
            "$meta" : "textScore"
        }
    }
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working in Loopback by using aggregate instead of the find method.

```
const db = Vehicletest.getDataSource().connector;
const collection = db.collection(Vehicletest.modelName);
var cursor = collection.aggregate([{ $match: { $text: { $search: searchText } } }, { $sort: { score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }, { $project: { name: 1 } }], {cursor: { batchSize: 1 }});
cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
  console.log(docs);
});
```

If you look at textSearch in the mongo documentation. There is a subsection called "text-search-in-aggregation" which has more details. Hope this helps!

Comment: You may be up to something, but that part is just about the `textSearch`(which can also be achieved within their syntax this way: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/630#issuecomment-201841867), the real deal here is how to do the `textScore` part

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use mongodb's driver directly as it seems that `textScore` is not supported in the builtin filters. So following the example of @edison-vs-tesla, it should look like this:

```
//first get the driver through datasource's connector
const db = Vehicletest.getDataSource().connector;
const collection = db.collection(Vehicletest.modelName);
collection.find(
  { $text: { $search: text } },
  { projection: { fieldName: true, score: { $meta: 'textScore' } } }
)
.sort({ score: { $meta: 'textScore' } })
.toArray(function(err, items) {
  console.log(items); //results
});
```

A full example for Loopback 4 can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jgutix/71cbb8a9f5946ecd57328862154e3c15